# How to trigger AWS Lambda Function via Telegram Messafe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, telegram

I want to trigger my lambda function via telegram messages. My project is that every time a message is sent to a telegram channel, the lambda function should be triggered. I managed to run my lambda function and the test was successful but i failed to trigger it automatically. I tried to use AWS SNS and AWS SQS. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Both SNS and SQS integrate with AWS Lambda. Do you have some way to integrate Telegram with SNS or SQS? If you want help with that specifically, you should explain in detail what you've done and how it's failing.

Comment: Actually, I managed to integrate SNS and SQS with AWS Lambda but I could not integrate SNS or SQS with Telegram. How can i send a message to SNS or SQS when a message is sent to a Telegram channel. By the way, I am open to other suggestions apart from SNS and SQS.

Comment: Search for a library that implements a Telegram channel listener e.g. [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/). Write a listener app, then enhance that app to emit events to SNS or SQS to trigger a Lambda function.